# How can I use rewrite-target on the root path with Azure Kubernetes Service?

Tags: kubernetes, ingress, azure-kubernetes-service, ingress-nginx

I want to have an API service that I want to reach under `/api`, and other requests to fall back to a frontend service.

Peculiar is that this worked locally with minikube, but now that I deployed on Azure Kubernetes Service (I used [this official MS tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic) to add an ingress controller), I can not get it to work.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: api-service
            port:
              number: 9002
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend-service
            port:
              number: 9001
```

That worked just fine on minikube, but on AKS, this causes **a timeout** when I try to open the publicly available IP. I have tried the following things:

- Change the frontend path to `(/|$)(.*)`
  Together with changing the rewrite-target to `/$2`. `kubectl` **will not even deploy** this because the path needs to be absolute.
- Change the frontend path to `/`
  Now **everything returns the frontend index.html**, even if the request is for `/style.css` or `favicon.ico` etc. (unless it starts with `/api`).
- Change the frontend path to `/` and remove the rewrite-target
  Then the frontend works fine, but **the api service doesn't "fit"** as intended. The api service has a call `/get-employee`, which I want to call under `/api/get-employee`, but I can't do that unless the api service itself would already have it under `/api/get-employee`.

How can I add a "root" or "fallback" service while still using rewrite-target?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when trying Microsofts tutorial. Adding `host` under the `rules` section worked for me.

**Example:**

```
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: {your_app}.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /test(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: mockserver-service
            port:
              number: 1234
```